# Nativescript Firebase offline authentication

Tags: firebase-authentication, nativescript, offline

My app uses nativescript-plugin-firebase to access the backend service, for authentication, database queries etc. However, authentication does not seem to work in offline conditions, which is a bit annoying... 
Currently I save user session in my local app configuration file for automatic login, but it freezes when it tries to login in firebase. Is there a way to enable offline authentication ?

Comment: How would authentication work when you're offline? How can the app ensure that you are who you claim to be without checking against the server?

Answer (score 0):

You can't / shouldn't do authentication offline. But once authenticated (while online), Firebase can catch the session and data which could be used offline.